# Bluemix binding WIoTP service using cf bind-service custom configuration

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, watson-iot

Cloud foundry provides facility to specify credentials as part of `cf bind-service` command. I am using this facility to specify custom credentials while binding WIoTP service to an app in Bluemix. As in below anonymized command

```
 cf bind-service demo-app dev-iotf-service -c   '{"apiKey":"a-dummyorg-dummy12345","apiToken":"dummyapikey","base_uri":"https://dummyorg.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:443/api/v0001","http_host":"dummyorg.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com","iotCredentialsIdentifier":"dummyid","mqtt_host":"dummyorg.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com","mqtt_s_port":8883,"mqtt_u_port":1883,"org":"dummyorg"}'
```

I have generated service-key using `cf create-service-key` command.

> Invalid configuration provided for -c flag. Please provide a valid
>   JSON object or path to a file containing a valid JSON object.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it that Bluemix,WIoTP currently doesn't support specifying custom credentials as part of `cf bind-service` command. I really don't want to go CUPs route as that would need change in quite a few apps which expect WIoTP credentials to be present in `iotf-service` object.

Comment: Please include the exact command you use (well, edit any keys).

Comment: Please provide more details about the command you are using.    Are you creating a JSON file with credentials or supplying them inline?  Specifically, what credentials are you trying to specify?

Comment: @ValerieLampkin Exact anonymized command included. I am supplying credentials inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can invoke the command exactly as you have specified (apart from substituting my app and service name) using bx client:

`bx cf bind-service myapp my-iotf-service -c   '{"apiKey":"a-dummyorg-dummy12345","apiToken":"dummyapikey","base_uri":"https://dummyorg.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:443/api/v0001","http_host":"dummyorg.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com","iotCredentialsIdentifier":"dummyid","mqtt_host":"dummyorg.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com","mqtt_s_port":8883,"mqtt_u_port":1883,"org":"dummyorg"}'`

and it works.  Possibly you simply have an old cf client.  You should use the bx client as available at https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/index.html#downloads

However, IoTP does not support this and so ignores anything sent via this means.  The obvious case would be to either create a limited API key or use an API key you have already created as you are attempting.  Unfortunately you would need to submit an idea at https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/?category=6343565373323972470 to get it considered.